# Spotify Authorization from Node Server not working with curl

Tags: node.js, spotify

I have a node server which gets an access token from Spotify's Web API. The response looks like this:

```
Response:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"type\":\"success\",\"done\":{\"json\":{\"access_token\":\"BQDqtYhVpafUIMYtZbwmy6iJcC_wvzR9Xrw6bRDFfpL3zZYfkCp2-KZaQVS-ZoElMF1czAl_B1vEaDrtPBOElSV3D5k\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600,\"scope\":\"user-top-read\"}}}",
  "headers": {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token"
  }
}
```

When I try to use the access_token on Spotify's [online API tool](https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-current-user-top-artists-and-tracks/?type=artists), I get an error for incomplete JSON. I think this is because the token I generate is only 91 characters long while the code they generate is 171 characters long. Why is my auth code so short?

I want an access token so I can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-spotify-api) react module for accessing my top tracks.

Here is my code for getting the access token:

```
let getAccessToken = (queryStringParameters) => {
        let url = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token';
        let encoded = (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'));
        console.log("encoded = " + encoded);

        let params = {
            grant_type: 'authorization_code',
            username: username,
            password: password,
            scope: scope
        };

        const formParams = Object.keys(params).map((key) => {
            return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
        }).join('&');

        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Basic ' + encoded,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: formParams
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(util.inspect(response, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
                return response.json();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                done({
                    error: error
                });
            });
    };
```

Comment: to confirm, with the online tool did you use exactly this as the access token: `BQDqtYhVpafUIMYtZbwmy6iJcC_wvzR9Xrw6bRDFfpL3zZYfkCp2-KZaQVS-ZoElMF1czAl_B1vEaDrtPBOElSV3D5k` - When I use this now it seems to think it is a valid (but nevertheless exipred) token

Comment: Yes I did, it resulted in no response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Authorisation Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) the **authorization_code** grant type only takes the **code** and **redirect URI** values. Not sure why the username and password ones you provide are even accepted, it is possible the token returned is a client credentials one as those tend to be shorter, that only access non-user related endpoints like loading Artist data, but the parameters you're providing appear to be undocumented at least in that guide.

Comment: I was following this specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4
Section 4.3.2 or Section 2.3.1